# It is very easy to accidentally turn off the "Apply this pattern on save". Is there any way make this more difficult or at least add a confirmation?

Tags: genexus

When I am editing an object that is using a pattern, it is easy to accidentally turn off "**Apply this pattern on save**" and not notice that you have done it. Eventually you notice that your changes are not being applied when you save, but you can end up wasting quote a bit of time until you realize what is happening.

It would be very nice if this control was more difficult to turn off or if it required a confirmation.

Comment: Disabling "Apply on save" shouldn't prevent you from seeing those changes at runtime, as a general Build of the main object that reaches those generated objects, or simply a Build All, should apply the changes when doing the "Refreshing instance" step when the build starts. What pattern are you using?

Comment: We use the WorkWithPlus pattern.  Source changes do continue to flow through, but if you are making changes to the instance they are not applied until you turn "Apply this pattern on save" back on.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have a confirmation if you remove the checkbox.  It is too easy to do that without even knowing it.  Seems like you realize it is unchecked when your changes in the pattern instance never come over to your runtime application.  You can waste a lot of time that could be completely avoided if there was a confirmation.